# How do I view the string inside a string resource after clicking on it?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

## Background

In android studio, [String Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource) store strings inside an xml strings.xml file and can be called in code like so:

[image]

Android Studio also has the convenient feature of previewing what is inside these resources inline:

[image]

---

## Issue

When you click on the hint, it goes from the hint:

[image]

To the actual reference of the resource:

[image]

It **does** revert to the hint *but only after navigating away from the file and returning to it after some time*.

---

## Question

Is there another way to revert a reference to a string resource back to a hint **other than** navigating a way then returning to the file after a few minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this,

Click on `R.string.yes` then press `Ctrl and -` to collapse and `Ctrl and +` to expand.

Answer (score 1):

Right click, `Folding`  and   `Collapse` or `Expand`

Comment: This, in addition to @prashant17's answer worked.